# Atom Tex editor cannot install any package

Tags: atom-editor

I cannot able to install any packages on atom. It gives me the below error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11pQY.jpg)

Comment: There are several possible solutions, without error message it hard to say whats wrong.
* If you have VPN disable it
* Change your DNS, or change temporarly to 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8
* launch Atom as administrator